# Delays between requests in wget

Tags: wget

I want to download web using wget, but to make it more like a real user I would like to make small random delays between requests.
I'm executing wget via cmd.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can add the below code into your command line which adds a ten second wait in between server requests.

> -w 10

And you can also include

> --random-wait

Into  your command line with -w option which will vary the wait by 0.5 and 1.5 times the value you provide here.

Answer (score 7):

Perfect, adding "-w 3" on the front end of a recursive download prevented the server from becoming overloaded.

as in

wget -w 3 -m -np -c -R "index.html*" "http://example.com.whatever/public/files/"

- wait 3
- mirroring to recurse all folder depths, and use source timestamps
- no parent upward traversal
- continue partially downloads
- reject any files named index.html
- target host URL with the desired recursive files and folders

hope this helps someone else

Comment: thank you for the details on these options. It really helped me! :)